# What is the difference between npm start and http-server?

Tags: web, npm, server, web-development-server, npm-start

I am a beginner in web development. These two confuse me. If they both open up a page in localhost then why do I need to install http-server instead of just using npm start?

Comment: We have no idea what the npm start script is running in your specific project, so it's hard to say. If you're using Create React App, for example, npm start runs a dev server whereas http-server can be used to serve the static production build outputs.

Answer (score 2):

`npm start` runs whatever command is specified in the "start" script in your package.json. From the npm docs:

> This runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start" property of its "scripts" object. If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-start

So if your `package.json` contains the following:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "echo Hello"
  }
}
```

Then running `npm start` will print "Hello". The `npm start` script is not an executable itself; it just runs whatever is specified in your package.json.

`http-server` on the other hand is a specific executable that starts an HTTP server. It may refer to the [http-server](https://github.com/http-party/http-server) npm package, or a different script with that name available in your command line interface.

`npm start` is a convention often used by other tools, e.g. testing or continuous integration, to "start up" your app regardless of what technology it is using. A common set up would be to specify the specific startup script in your "start" script:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "http-server"
  }
}
```

While that makes `npm start` and `http-server` do the same thing in your project directory, other tools will rely on `npm start` since otherwise they wouldn't know that you wanted to use `http-server` as your startup script.

Answer (score 0):

[`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) is an HTTP server written in JavaScript for Node.js.

[`npm start`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-start) runs the `start` script specified in `package.json`. It *might* run a web server (which **might** be written using `http-server`) and open a browser to it. It might do something else. It's entirely configurable.